# How do you backup Xampp directory?

Tags: file, backup, xampp, transfer

I want to both backup my Xampp directory and also transfer it to another computer.

Is there an easy way to do this?

When I try to copy it, it gives me a restriction, even though I am not running xampp at the time.

Thank you!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that rsync would be quite a good way of doing this you could either backup the entire directory or you can use the "--files-from=" parameter to specify a file containing a list of what you want to backup, aka the htdocs directory and config files.

You could have a look at the rsync [example page](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/examples.html) this covers both local and remote backups.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the services turned off (apache, mysql, ftp, etc..). Go to start->run->services.msc